# Magento 2 How to validate newly added field in cart price rule

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, custom-field, condition, validate

I have added a new field in the Cart Price Rule form as below. I have saved the value in the table as a new column

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="rule_information" sortOrder="10">
        <field name="store_ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Cms\Options</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">int</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Store View Test</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sales_rule</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_ids</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]
Now I have to validate this condition in the rule validator. How can I do it?

Comment: pls add the field screenshot

Comment: @RohanHapani Updated the screenshot

Comment: Youjust want to add multi select as required. right?

Comment: @RohanHapani Yes, I need the selected store ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with validate tag below new field.

Otherwise, Magento also supports you validate server side through by:

<backend_model>[Name_Company][Name_module]\Model\Config\Backend[Name_Class]
Magento 2 already defined some validation classes

Comment: I have to validate this condition in the rule validator, not in admin form

Comment: Then try with backend_model, declare a class which is inherited from parent class \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value. The parent class supports functions such as beforeSave, afterSave, getData.

Comment: I need to validate the store id condition in FE. Like the customer group